# JQuery: on click does not work

Tags: jquery

It's weird, but on click event does not work. There is no error in the code, I used Firebug.

```
    $('#tri1').on('click', function () {
        alert("foo");
    });
```

Please see [a domenstration at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejAYp/1/).

Comment: #tri1 is the blue triangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `#tri1` is covered by `#text1`.  Try this:

```
        $('#text1').on('click', function () {
            alert("Sasa");
        });
```

Comment: True but I think the OP here want to identify clicking anywhere in the triangle. This way it will work only if clicking on the text. See in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejAYp/13/), clicking outside a text will being wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this

$('#TextWrapper div').on('click', function () {
                alert("foo");
            });
```